# unity 2019 error in android build configuration

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, build

I face this problem both in a worked project and in a new one. It does not give me the option to configure to compile on Android.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Are you using Android SDK downloaded with Unity Hub, or custom? I suppose something is wrong with your SDK, have you installed new Unity version? Make sure in Unity Hub that you have android SDK, NDK, JDK installed

[image: Unity Hub Add Modules]

And External Tools are set properly in Unity Preferences:

[image: Unity Preferences]

Comment: No you need license to remove splash screen or if you hit 100k$/year. My version is free (premium got black skin)